# c# Background Task only runs 1 time?

Tags: c#, background-task

Hi so i wane do a background task with my code but the code only runs 1 time when i startup my application. i have put a break point already in my infinity loop but that doesn't get triggerd. So i was wondering what can be the issue. my task is doing a test if my data is coming in my google calendar. Its a check. I hope somebody can help me out.

```
protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string DbConnectionString = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Site:ConnectionString");

            using (IDbConnection conn = OpenConnection(DbConnectionString))
            {
                List<GoogleAccess> googleCredentials = conn.Query<Domain.GoogleAccess>("Select g.Id, g.CalendarId, g.RefreshToken, convert(nvarchar(36), g.CompanyUserId) as CompanyUserId from [dbo].[googleAccess] g", null, commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();

                // list with all users

                foreach (var credential in googleCredentials.Where(e => e.RefreshToken is not null).ToList())
                {
                    var accessToken = RefreshToken(credential.RefreshToken);

                    // search all events Where that contain CompanyUserTreatmentId From that user
                    var allReservations = await TurnUp.Admin.Infrastructure.RestAPI.Reservation.GetAll(new Models.RestAPI.Reservation.PostModel.GetAllReservationPostModel() { });

                    var covertedList = new List<EventModel>();

                    foreach (var reservation in allReservations.result.items.Where(e => e.isCancelled == false).ToList())
                    {
                        covertedList.Add(new EventModel
                        {
                            Id = reservation.id.ToString(),
                            Description = reservation.description,
                            Start = new EventDateTime { DateTime = DateTime.Parse(reservation.startTime.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"), TimeZone = "Europe/Zurich" },
                            End = new EventDateTime { DateTime = DateTime.Parse(reservation.endTime.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"), TimeZone = "Europe/Zurich" },
                            Summary = reservation.description
                        });
                    }

                    //Retrieving all Google Events from google api
                    var allGoogleEvents = new List<EventModel>();
                    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"));
                    RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();

                    //Send parameters with the request 
                    restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKeys}");
                    restRequest.AddParameter("maxResults", 2500);
                    restRequest.AddParameter("OrderBy", "startTime");
                    restRequest.AddParameter("showDeleted", "false");
                    restRequest.AddParameter("timeMin", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"));
                    restRequest.AddParameter("timeMax", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(6).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"));
                    restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                    restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                    try
                    {
                        //Get request to server
                        var response = restClient.Get(restRequest);

                        //check if response is ok
                        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            //change response to an class that can be used
                            JObject calendarEvents = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                            var test = calendarEvents["nextSyncToken"].ToString();
                            allGoogleEvents = calendarEvents["items"].ToObject<List<EventModel>>();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Coulden't connect to google agenda.");
                    }

                    //list with reservations that arn't in google
                    var newList = covertedList.Except(allGoogleEvents).Concat(allGoogleEvents.Except(covertedList));
                    //var newList = googleEventList.Except(covertedList).Concat(covertedList.Except(googleEventList));

                    foreach (var ev in newList)
                    {
                        var restClientForAddingEvents = new RestClient();
                        var restRequestForAddingEvents = new RestRequest();
                        restClientForAddingEvents.BaseUrl = new System.Uri($"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{credential.CalendarId}/events");

                        EventModel newEvent = new EventModel();

                        newEvent.Start.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ev.Start.DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
                        newEvent.End.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(ev.End.DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
                        newEvent.Description = ev.Description;
                        newEvent.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

                        var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newEvent, new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                        });

                        //Send parameters with the request
                        restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKeys}");
                        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", model, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                        //RestClient restClient = new RestClient(new Uri($"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/" + ev.Id.ToString().Replace("-", "")));
                        //RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();

                        ////Send parameters with the request
                        //restRequest.AddQueryParameter("key", $"{ApiKeys}");
                        //restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accestoken);
                        //restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                        try
                        {
                            //Post request to server
                            var restResponse = restClient.Post(restRequest);

                            //check if response is ok
                            if (restResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Coulden't Create an event in google agenda.");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: I think it simply crashes somewhere.

Comment: That catches in `BackgroundService` help only when you use some external logging.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the ExecuteAsync() method and go line by line checking out where it breaks out from the flow it's supposed to go. At simple view can't see anything out of place (maybe reduce the size of the method sample)

Comment: Any exception will break your loop since you don't have try-catch around the whole thing inside the loop.

Comment: ok i found my exception but its in the status code it return Conflict how do i handle this of?